# Error al ejecutar un store procedure dentro de un package en Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-11g

La versión que me devuelve la instancia cuando ejecuto el query `select * from v$version;` es la siguiente:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.2.0  Production  
TNS for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

El package que modifiqué y quiero llamar es *BZPIDEC* y el store procedure, `P_SELECT_RECORDS_SZVMEET`, el cual solamente contiene dos parámetros de salida, ninguno de entrada. El dueño del paquete es el usuario `BANINST1`:

```sql
PROCEDURE P_SELECT_RECORDS_SZVMEET (
    p_meetcode OUT NUMBER,
    p_meetdesc OUT VARCHAR2) 
        is
        BEGIN 
            SELECT SZVMEET.SZVMEET_CODE,
                   SZVMEET.SZVMEET_DESC 
            INTO p_meetcode,
                p_meetdesc
            FROM SZVMEET;
        END;
```

La manera en cómo estoy haciendo la ejecución del store procedure es desde *SQL Developer*, pero el manejador me marca en rojo el nombre del usuario propietario:

```sql
DECLARE
    code int;
    descripcion varchar2(1000);

    BEGIN
      EXECUTE  BANINST1.BZPIDEC.P_SELECT_RECORDS_SZVMEET();
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(code,descripcion);
    END;
```

Luego de ejecutar me devuelve el siguiente error que empieza en la línea 7 del comando antes mencionado:

```
ORA-06550: línea 7, columna 12:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BANINST1" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ; immediate
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "BANINST1" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0):

pedi ayuda a un amigo, me dijo que revisara el package si compilo bien.
cuando observo el body del cuerpo el manejador lo marcaba con una X roja que inidcaba un mal compilacion